# 3D plot from lists

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, regions, data

I'm trying to generate a 3D plot of some functions a,b,c, under certain inequality constraints. I have earlier defined the functions

```
a[x,y,z],b[x,y,z],c[x,y,z]
```

and

```
f[a[x,y,z],b[x,y,z],c[x,y,z]]
```

So far I have:

```
RegionPlot3D[
0 < f[a[x, y, z], b[x, y, z], c[x, y, z]] && 
0 < a[x, y, z] < 1 && 0 < b[x, y, z] < 1 && 0 < c[x, y, z] < 1, 
{x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {y, 200, 2000}, {z, 100, 1000}]
```

This works great, and gives me a 3D plot showing the region in x, y, z space for which the constraint holds.

---

Now, I have lists of a,b,c from another calculation, i.e.,

```
mat=Table[{a[i],b[i],c[i]},{i,0,10}] 
alist=mat[[All,1]]
```

Essentially I want to use a similar RegionPlot3D code to plot the space in x, y, z for which the a,b,c values *from the dataset* fulfill the conditions (inequalities).

I'm struggling with:

- Properly ordering/pairing my data sets, such as to thread each set of corresponding a, b and c values together
- Calling values from the data table in the RegionPlot3D, i.e. running it for every data point in the table a, b, c
- Plotting this on a 3D plot in terms of x,y,z. So essentially I have the functions a[x,y,z],b[x,y,z],c[x,y,z] and separately lists of a, b, c values.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is `{x,y,z} -> {a,b,c}` an invertible transformation? It may not be possible to determine the appropriate `{x,y,z}` points for plotting if they are not and the original `{x,y,z}` points are not otherwise available. Otherwise consider using `ListPointPlot3D` and `Select`.

Comment: @eyorble - I am not sure they are. What is the procedure if they are?


ListPointPlot3D looks like it could be useful. I'm not sure how I could enforce the inequality condition though (which I have in the region plot). I'm also struggling with the general task of choosing data sets as my dependent and independent variables, for a plot, particularly the latter..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegionPlot from list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174700/regionplot-from-list)