# RegionPlot from list

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, regions

I would like to plot a [`RegionPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html) for $f(x,y) > 0$ where instead of specifying the range of $x$ and $y$ I want to use a list of `{{x1,y1},{x2,y2}...,{xn,yn}}` points that I have, as the inputs.

Any suggestions on how to do this would be great!

Answer (score 5):

ConvexHullMesh may be what you are looking for:
 ["The convex hull mesh is the smallest convex set that includes the points..."](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConvexHullMesh.html)

```
list = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {100, 2}];
Show[ListPlot[list], RegionPlot[ConvexHullMesh[list]]]
```

[image]

Or did you mean something more like this:

```
region = Polygon[{{-1, -1}, {1.5, 0}, {-2, 2}}];
f[x_, y_] = E^-(x^2 + y^2);
Plot3D[If[RegionMember[region, {x, y}], f[x, y], Indeterminate], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a list of $(x_i,y_i)$ values

```
list = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {100, 2}];
```

We can get the range using [`MinMax`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MinMax.html) for each axis.

```
MinMax /@ Transpose[list]
```

Or using [`CoordinateBounds`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoordinateBounds.html), with identical results (credit to Carl Woll for pointing this out in the comments).

```
CoordinateBounds[list]
```

Now we can use that as an argument for [`RegionPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html) taking advantage of [`Sequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html) and [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) (`@@`)

```
RegionPlot[
   x^2 + y^2 < 2
   , {x, Sequence @@ #1}
   , {y, Sequence @@ #2}
   ] & @@ CoordinateBounds[list]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: In M10.1+ you could instead use [`CoordinateBounds`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoordinateBounds).

Comment: @CarlWoll Thanks, answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you are asking for:

```
f[x_, y_] = Cos[2*2*3.14 Sqrt[x ^2 + y^2]];
list = {{0, -0.5}, {-1, 1}, {1, 1}};
xrange = {x, Min[list[[;; , 1]]], Max[list[[;; , 1]]]};
yrange = {y, Min[list[[;; , 2]]], Max[list[[;; , 2]]]};
RegionPlot[f[x, y] > 0 && RegionMember[Polygon[list], {x, y}], xrange, yrange]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ImplicitRegion[f[x, y] > 0, {x, y}]` as the first argument in `RegionPlot` with the option `PlotRange -> CoordinateBounds[pts]` without having to specify the ranges of `x` and `y`:

```
f[x_, y_] := 1 - (x^2 + y^2)
pts = RandomReal[{-5, 5}, {30, 2}];
RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[f[x, y] > 0, {x, y}], PlotRange->  CoordinateBounds[pts]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use `PlotRange -> PlotRange[ListPlot @ pts]`:

```
RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[2 - x^2 - y > 0, {x, y}], PlotRange -> PlotRange[ListPlot@pts]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Using `BoundingRegion`:**

```
f[x_, y_] := 1 - (x^2 + y^2)
pts = RandomReal[{-5, 5}, {30, 2}];
breg = BoundingRegion[pts];

reg = ImplicitRegion[f[x, y] > 0, {x, y}];

RegionPlot[reg
 , PlotRange -> (List @@ breg // Transpose)
 , Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4]
   , Point@pts}
 ]
```

---

[image]